# React isNaN with input type number

Tags: reactjs, nan

I need to check for NaN before I store a value with useState in my React Hooks application, but it doesn't seem to be checking?

```
const handleStartValueChange = (value) => {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(value)) ) {
            setStartValue(0);
        }
        setStartValue(parseInt(value));
    };
```

This is called from onChange on an input box with type number

```
<div className="startValueHeader">Start value</div>
                        <input
                            value={startValue}
                            type="number"
                            className="startValueValue"
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                handleStartValueChange(event.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
```

What am I missing?

The reason I need to check for NaN is I need to store a value of 0 instead of '' when I clear the input field

Comment: add `console.log(value)` into `handleStartValueChange` and see what you actually get

Comment: `parseInt(value)` always converts string to a number. and type=number doesn't allow string inputs

Comment: Then why do I get NaN in the DOM?

Comment: add a return statement after setStartValue(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Number - convert numeric strings and null to numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers)

> ```
> Number('123')     // 123
> Number('12.3')    // 12.3
> Number('12.00')   // 12
> Number('123e-1')  // 12.3
> Number('')        // 0 <--- you need this
> Number(null)      // 0
> Number('0x11')    // 17
> Number('0b11')    // 3
> Number('0o11')    // 9
> Number('foo')     // NaN
> Number('100a')    // NaN
> Number('-Infinity') //-Infinity
> ```

```
const handleStartValueChange = value => {
  const number = Number(value); // converts '' from empty input -> 0
  setStartValue(number)
};
```

[image: Edit thirsty-snyder-ywi7q]

**NOTE**: If you instead specify `defaultValue` the input won't display the "0" when empty.